# Term for multiple disconnected areas

Tags: terminology

Consider the white patches in the following image which can be thought of as sets of $(x, y)$ ordered pairs on an $xy$ plane. We can say the the image has 4 white patches (may or may not include boundaries) and we can also say that the image has one *insert-term-here* which is the union of all those sets.

What are the appropriate terms for the individual patches (where all points are "connected") and for the union of all of these patches?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The individual patches are the **connected components** of the set of white points.

Comment: Does this terminology come from topology?

Comment: It is either topology (if you think of the image as a rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$), or graph theory if you think of it as a graph (vertices corresponding to pixels, edges joining nearest neighbours).